# Python reload function with annotation

Tags: python

How do I reload modules containing functions with annotations in Python? I tried the methods in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module), but none of them seem to work

```
@task
def move_to_new_mastery(*args):
    #for all students and subtopics, recalculate mastery
    logger.info('hi')
    return 13
```

Is there a way to reload modules with functions with annotations or do I need to reload each function individually?

Comment: I think you'll have to be a bit more specific about what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: functions are first class objects in Python: why reload and not simply redefine?

Comment: `reload` can only reload modules, no single functions, no single classes, only all thet is in the module. Are you sure that you want to reaload a single function? There might be other objects holding a reference to that function. I think it is possible but is this really what you need?